# Compiler dependency of searching a value in array of pointers to array of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d

The following code have an array named `ReadOnly[]`  which contains elements that are pointers to other arrays like `AV_ReadOnly`, `BV_ReadOnly` etc. Again `AV_ReadOnly`, `BV_ReadOnly` etc are pointer arrays containing elements that points to integer arrays.

The `read_arrays()` is a function used for printing a particular list/ accessing any particular value of the integer arrays. This approach works well on the test environment.   But is there a chance for failure of this approach with a change in the platform/compiler?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int AV1_ReadOnly[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int AV2_ReadOnly[] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

int BV1_ReadOnly[] = { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30};
int BV2_ReadOnly[] = { 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40};

int MV1_ReadOnly[] = { 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50};
int MV2_ReadOnly[] = { 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60};

int NC1_ReadOnly[] = { 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70};
int NC2_ReadOnly[] = { 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80};

int * AV_ReadOnly[] =
{
  AV1_ReadOnly,
  AV2_ReadOnly,
};

int * BV_ReadOnly[] = 
{
   BV1_ReadOnly,
   BV2_ReadOnly,
};  

int * MV_ReadOnly[] =
{
  MV1_ReadOnly,
  MV2_ReadOnly,
};

int * NC_ReadOnly[] = 
{
   NC1_ReadOnly,
   NC2_ReadOnly
};  

int ** ReadOnly[] =
{
   AV_ReadOnly,
   BV_ReadOnly,
   MV_ReadOnly,
   NC_ReadOnly
};


void read_arrays( int obj, int inst )
{
int ** ArrayPtr = ReadOnly[obj];

 int count =0;
   while( count <8 )
   {
      printf( "\n %d", *(ArrayPtr[inst]+count) );
      count++;
   }
}


void main()
{
   read_arrays( 1,1 );
}
```

Comment: What make you think this is platform/compiler dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be OK as long as you keep the `int` arrays and the `int*` arrays in the same file.

Also, you can (should) declare them `const` if you have no intentions to change them.

Also, you can (should) declare them `static` if you have no intentions to `extern` them in other files.

BTW, from what you've published, it looks like you can simply use `int table[8][10]` instead...

Comment: What if I want to access this over files putting the array names into the .h file

Comment: Then **don't** use `static` in that case. In the header file, declare them with `extern` (without initializing them of course), and in other files simply include this header file.

Comment: which something, by design, you don't want to do? That means an external file can change them without the 'source' file noticing this. Would be better to then go for 'getter' methods instead of making them extern through the header...